# Android app keeps crashing in android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw

Tags: android, crashlytics, viewgroup

Crashlytics sends many crash logs everyday on this crash, but I have no idea at all how to locate the bug. 
Any suggestion on where should I start to investigate it?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2488)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10433)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10433)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10433)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10997)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10435)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10433)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10433)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10997)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2126)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10435)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:899)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1910)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2445)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4484)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Do you have xml like LinearLayout->5more.. ->LinearLayout.

Comment: the stack trace says it clear: the filename where you have NPE is android/view/ViewGroup.java at line 2488

Comment: @pskink it's ViewGroup's code.

Comment: i know its ViewGroup, take a look at that and find out what's wrong

Comment: It's because there are too many Nested views.

Comment: how do you know that?

Comment: @tiny sunlight  Doesn't android support too many nested views? Is there a defined threshold?

Comment: I think it's good to make layout simple.There is not  defined threshold.

Comment: Can you repeat this error youself .I think you are using sth in wrong way.

Comment: No, I can't reproduce it. This is why I'm asking where to start.....